# Apache command line parser bug?

Tags: java, command-line-interface, apache-commons-cli

I got the code below from a sample code from tutorials point and tweaked it a little bit.

**App.java**

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
        CommandTest t = new CommandTest();
        t.start(args);
}
```

**CommandTest.java**

```
public class CommandTest {

    void start(String[] args) throws ParseException {

          //***Definition Stage***
          // create Options object
          Options options = new Options();

          // add option "-a"
          options.addOption(
                    Option.builder("a")
                        .longOpt("add")
                        .desc("add numbers")
                        .hasArg(false)
                        .valueSeparator('=')
                        .required(false)
                        .build()
                  );

          // add option "-m"
          options.addOption("m", false, "");
          options.addOption(
                    Option.builder("m")
                        .longOpt("multiply")
                        .desc("multiply numbers")
                        .hasArg(false)
                        .valueSeparator('=')
                        .required(false)
                        .build()
                  );

          //***Parsing Stage***
          //Create a parser
          CommandLineParser parser = new DefaultParser();

          //parse the options passed as command line arguments
          CommandLine cmd = parser.parse( options, args);

          //***Interrogation Stage***
          //hasOptions checks if option is present or not
          if(cmd.hasOption("a")) { 
             System.out.println("Sum of the numbers: " + getSum(args));
          } else if(cmd.hasOption("m")) {
             System.out.println("Multiplication of the numbers: " + getMultiplication(args));
          }
       }

       public static int getSum(String[] args) {
          int sum = 0;
          for(int i = 1; i < args.length ; i++) {
             sum += Integer.parseInt(args[i]);
          } 
          return sum;
       }

       public static int getMultiplication(String[] args) {
          int multiplication = 1;
          for(int i = 1; i < args.length ; i++) {
             multiplication *= Integer.parseInt(args[i]);
          } 
          return multiplication;
       }
}
```

Now, my question is that, when i try to execute the above code with a parameter of `-multi` it will still be accepted? I've already set the options to receive only either `-m` or `-multiply`. However, it will still accept `-multi`

I am using commons-cli-1.3.1 (im trying to debug a legacy code by the way)

Note: Above source is a SAMPLE source only, no need to apply actual coding guidelines (good or bad) i just want to know why the behavior happens as it is.

Comment: *I've already set the options to receive only either -m or -multiply* - `longOpt` uses double dash, so your options are `-m` or `--multiply`. `-multi` isn't allowed. if this code is correct you'll get a `ParseException` for unknown option `multi`. Please post the part which calls the `start` method too. Also, `options.addOption("m", false, "")` isn't needed, since you redeclaring that option right after.

Comment: sorry, i've deleted `options.addOption("m", false, "")`. Also, i've updated the source above. `-multi` does not throw any exception.

Comment: Your updated code doesn't compile. Please take your time to test your code and make sure to post a complete and verifiable example which reproduces the issue.

Comment: i've update the code above to show all parts of the code

Comment: does `-m` and `-multi` the same in the eyes of command line parser? i mean when `hasOption` is executed with a `m` parameter. it still gives true

Comment: I had a look at the source code and yes, they are treated as the same option. Check my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the behaviour when a non-matching option gets found ([org.apache.commons.cli.Options:233](https://github.com/apache/commons-cli/blob/cli-1.3.1/src/main/java/org/apache/commons/cli/Options.java)):

```
public List<String> getMatchingOptions(String opt) {
  opt = Util.stripLeadingHyphens(opt);
  List<String> matchingOpts = new ArrayList();
  if (this.longOpts.keySet().contains(opt)) {
    return Collections.singletonList(opt);
  } else {
    Iterator var3 = this.longOpts.keySet().iterator();

    while(var3.hasNext()) {
      String longOpt = (String)var3.next();
      /******************************************************/
      /* longOpt = "multiply"                               */
      /* opt = "multi"                                      */
      /******************************************************/
      if (longOpt.startsWith(opt)) {
        matchingOpts.add(longOpt);
      }
      /******************************************************/
    }

    return matchingOpts;
  }
}
```

As you can see in the highlighted block, if a short option isn't matched the library searches for the first long option that partially matches the entered option. It uses `startsWith`, and since `"multiply".startsWith("multi")` is `true` it defaults to option `--multiply`.

Comment: is this the same with `hasOptions`?, it seems when i try to see the one you referred, `getMatchingOptions` is not used in `hasOptions`. Futhermore, `hasOptions` only excutes `containsKey`. Where does the above behaviour shown in `hasOptions`?

Comment: @lemoncodes What `hasOptions`? I can't seem to find that method in the source code, can you please link it?

Comment: sorry i meant `hasOption`. ie `cmd.hasOption("m")` or `cmd.hasOption("a")`.